# Using ActionBarSherlock Menus shows old menu button on new 4.0 and higher - Picture Included

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I've been looking for a while and I just want to know whether or not I'm wating my time trying to get rid of the little menu icon that show's up in my app to support older applications that don't have the ActionBar implemented.

[image]

How do I get rid of it (as a bonus: does it have an actual name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the bonus: it's called the *legacy* overflow button.

The correct way to get 'rid' of it on devices that do not implement a dedicated menu button, is to set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher. In that case, the system will not add the legacy overflow button.

There is a small exception though: if you do not use the `ActionBar`, set `minSdkVersion` to 10 or lower and set `targetSdkVersion` to 11, 12, or 13, Android *will* add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

You can read all the details in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) on the Android dev website.

Comment: Thanks for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `targetSdkVersion` to 14 or higher.

Comment: @Jake Wharton : i am using you library to display action bar on 2.2 and > os .. i want an overflow icon like in this image http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KIyVJ4DBLdw/TyGbNsLn4hI/AAAAAAAABFs/xgLPIAaEP6I/s1600/image01.png .. please guide me on this